# Flink in ECS fails to find shaded ContainerCredentialsProvider

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to run Flink 1.7.2 on ECS with Fargate. I've set up the state backend for my job to be RocksDB with a path=s3://...

In my Dockerfile my base image is `1.7.2-hadoop27-scala_2.11`, and I run the following 2 commands:

```
RUN echo "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: org.apache.flink.fs.s3hadoop.shaded.com.amazonaws.auth.ContainerCredentialsProvider" >> "$FLINK_CONF_DIR/flink-conf.yaml"
RUN cp /opt/flink/opt/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.7.2.jar /opt/flink/lib/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.7.2.jar
```

Just like it says in
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8439

However I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: From option fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.flink.fs.s3hadoop.shaded.com.amazonaws.auth.ContainerCredentialsProvider not found
        at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.loadAWSProviderClasses(S3AUtils.java:592)
        at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.createAWSCredentialProviderSet(S3AUtils.java:556)
        at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.DefaultS3ClientFactory.createS3Client(DefaultS3ClientFactory.java:52)
        at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:256)
        at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.AbstractS3FileSystemFactory.create(AbstractS3FileSystemFactory.java:125)
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:395)
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:318)
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:298)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStorage.<init>(FsCheckpointStorage.java:58)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend.createCheckpointStorage(FsStateBackend.java:444)
        at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend.createCheckpointStorage(RocksDBStateBackend.java:407)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:249)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.flink.fs.s3hadoop.shaded.com.amazonaws.auth.ContainerCredentialsProvider not found
        at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2375)
        at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClasses(Configuration.java:2446)
        at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.loadAWSProviderClasses(S3AUtils.java:589)
        ... 28 more
```

Looking in the `flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.7.2.jar` I see that the package of the class `ContainerCredentialsProvider` is actually `org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.auth`

I already tried:

1. Adding the `aws-sdk-core` jar to the lib, and setting the credentials provider to be just `com.amazonaws.auth.ContainerCredentialsProvider` (without the shading) but I get the problem mentioned in the issue link above
2. Setting the credentials provider to be `org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.auth.ContainerCredentialsProvider` but then the code in `S3FileSystemFactory.java` prefixes it with `org.apache.flink.fs.s3hadoop.shaded.`

Any ideas here for finding the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was resolved in one of the versions after.

I ran it on **Flink 1.9.0** cluster with the following line:

```
RUN echo "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: com.amazonaws.auth.ContainerCredentialsProvider" >> "$FLINK_CONF_DIR/flink-conf.yaml"
```

and the class is found and works.

You can see in:
https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-filesystems/flink-s3-fs-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/fs/s3hadoop/S3FileSystemFactory.java

that the `FLINK_SHADING_PREFIX` is now correct